# How to get data from a stored Procedure that joins 3 tables and takes 3 different Parameters asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have to create something that executes a stored Procedure, and depending on the parameters passed it will show data from different Tables. I am using EF model.

The Parameters are @Username, @FamilyID, @CategoryID

If you run it with Just @Username it will retrieve Families

If you run it with @Username and @FamilyID it will retrieve Categories

If you run it with all parameters it will return Report Names

I'm very new to ASP.Net, and I was seeking for help to display the results of this stored procedure. I have succeeded on executing a stored procedure that uses one single table, but unfortunately haven't with this specific one...

SP

```
ALTER Procedure [Report].[Rep_ReportListforUser]  

@UserName varchar(50),
@FamilyId int = 0 ,
@CategoryID int = 0



as

Set nocount on


 



If @FamilyId = 0

Begin

Select RF.ID FamilyID,RF.Family FamilyName,1 Allowed

from Rep_ReportFamilies RF 

 

End

Else If @CategoryID = 0 

--Categories

Begin

Select Cat.Id CategoryID , Cat.Category ,Case when UF.ReportFamilyId is null then 0 else 1 end Allowed

from dbo.Rep_ReportFamilies RF Left Join dbo.Rep_User_Family UF On RF.ID = UF.ReportFamilyID

Join dbo.Rep_ReportCategories Cat on Cat.FamilyID = RF.ID  

where UserId = (Select UserID from Report.Users where Username = @UserName)

and RF.ID = @FamilyID
 

End

Else

Begin

Select RL.ReportID , ReportDescription ReportName, Case when RU.Userid is null then 0 else 1 end Allowed

from dbo.Rep_ReportNames RL 

Left Join dbo.Rep_Report_Users RU on RU.ReportId = RL.ReportId 

Where RL.CategoryID = @CategoryID and

 RU.userid  = (Select userid from Report.Users  
            where Username = @UserName)
            Order by ReportDescription

end
```

Code

```
            SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[] 
            {
                new SqlParameter ("@UserName","john"),
                new SqlParameter ("@FamilyId",10),
                new SqlParameter ("@CategoryID",24),
            };

            var families = context.Database.SqlQuery<Rep_ReportFamilies>("[Report].Rep_ReportListforUser @Family");
            var username = context.Database.SqlQuery<Rep_ReportNames>("[Report].Rep_ReportListforUser @UserName");
            var category = context.Database.SqlQuery<Rep_ReportNames>("[Report].Rep_ReportListforUser @CategoryID");

            return View();
        }
```

Hope Someone can Help

Happy Coding!

Comment: You need to start adding code snippets to your questions.

Comment: I have added the code, sorry I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

Need to update your code the following way.

Updated Code.

```js
// If you run it with Just @Username it will retrieve Families
 
var families =  context.Database.SqlQuery<Rep_ReportFamilies>("EXEC [Report].Rep_ReportListforUser @UserName, @FamilyId, @CategoryID ", 
                new SqlParameter ("@UserName","john"),
                new SqlParameter ("@FamilyId",0),
                new SqlParameter ("@CategoryID",0);             

//If you run it with @Username and @FamilyID it will retrieve Categories                
 var username = context.Database.SqlQuery<Rep_ReportFamilies>("EXEC [Report].Rep_ReportListforUser @UserName, @FamilyId, @CategoryID ", 
                new SqlParameter ("@UserName","john"),
                new SqlParameter ("@FamilyId",10),
                new SqlParameter ("@CategoryID",0);             

//If you run it with all parameters it will return Report Names
 var category = context.Database.SqlQuery<Rep_ReportFamilies>("EXEC [Report].Rep_ReportListforUser @UserName, @FamilyId, @CategoryID ", 
                new SqlParameter ("@UserName","john"),
                new SqlParameter ("@FamilyId",10),
                new SqlParameter ("@CategoryID",24);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: The idea is to create a side menu that will be populated with the results from the stored procedure.  So the first thing that will appear will be the report Family, then category, and then report Name. The reason I'm passing username is to make sure each user will only see what is allowed to (there is a boolean field for that). There are 4 tables involved in the stored Procedure, Do I have to execute that procedure for each table?

Comment: @SvenEberth Thank you very much for your help. Do I have to create a model for the data that will be retrieved from the stored procedure, that being ReportName, ReportFamily and ReportCategory?